# JMS message consumer could not receive messages from ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to consume messages from Artemis ActiveMQ version 2.19.0 with Spring Boot application but I'm getting error

```
2021-11-02 14:47:49.810 ERROR 4100 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'exampleQueue' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=39, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class SpringJmsConsumerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringJmsConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsFactory() throws JMSException {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "(tcp://amq1:61616,tcp://amq2:61616,tcp://amq3:61616)?" +
                        "ha=true&sslEnabled=true" +
                        "&trustStorePath=/home/broker_ts.p12&trustStorePassword=12345"
                        + "&keyStorePath=/home/client_ks.p12&keyStorePassword=123456"
        );
        factory.createConnection("admin", "admin");
        factory.setRetryInterval(1000);
        factory.setRetryIntervalMultiplier(1.0);
        factory.setReconnectAttempts(-1);
        factory.setConfirmationWindowSize(10);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException {
        return new JmsTemplate(jmsFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer consumer() {
        return new Consumer();
    }

}

public class Consumer {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @JmsListener(destination = "jms:queue:exampleQueue")
    public void receive(@Payload String msg, @Header("_AMQ_DUPL_ID") String messageId) {
        System.out.println("Received message: "  + messageId);
    }
}
```

I also tried to simplify the client's URL, e.g.:

```java
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsFactory() throws JMSException {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "tcp://amq1:61616"
        );
        factory.createConnection("admin", "admin");
        factory.setRetryInterval(1000);
        factory.setRetryIntervalMultiplier(1.0);
        factory.setReconnectAttempts(-1);
        factory.setConfirmationWindowSize(10);
        return factory;
    }
```

I also tried to use `@JmsListener(destination="exampleQueue")`, but I had the same error.

I had similar implementation for message producer with same Artemis connection url and I was using the same certificates and it was working fine.

Any ideas what's wrong in my implementation?

Here is the `acceptors` from `broker.xml` on the `amq1` broker:

```xml
<acceptors>
   <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://amq1:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/home/broker_ts.p12;keyStorePassword=12345</acceptor>
</acceptors>
```

On `amq2` and `amq3` I have `amq2:61616` and `amq3:61616` respectively. This is the only difference.

I also tried a simplified `acceptor`:

```xml
<acceptors>
   <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://amq1:61616</acceptor>
</acceptors>
```

Comment: I had the same error with that url too. I added acceptors in my main post

Comment: Do you mean without sslEnabled thing and other stuff, right ?

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help, same error

Comment: Can you ping the broker from the client?

Comment: The ping was working. I tried also to run this consumer client on the same server where is broker running and it was same error

Comment: So the broker and the client are running on the *same* machine and the client and broker both using `tcp://amq1:61616` for the URL and acceptor respectively and you're still getting, "AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers."? If so, are you sure nothing is blocking connections on port `61616`.

Comment: Using another port for acceptor should solve this problem with blocking connection on specific port right ?

Comment: It should work unless the other port you choose is also blocked (assuming that port blocking is the problem).

Comment: @JustinBertram but why then message producer works which is using the same connection url ? The message producer are running also on the same machine and works